# How to destroy/release resources used in 1 activity/layout?

Tags: android, resources, release, destroy

How do I release resources used in 1 activity?
So I got 3 layouts and activity for each layout, but the problem is when I switch between those activities my app crashes and I get this:
[image: logcat]

I started getting this error ever since I added adds to my application.
My whole logcat https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1s2j.png

XML Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#000000" >

      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/dugme2"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="90dp"
          android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dugme1"
          android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
          android:background="#0000"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:src="@drawable/dragunov" />

      <ImageButton
          android:id="@+id/dugme5"
          android:layout_width="150dp"
          android:layout_height="90dp"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignTop="@+id/dugme6"
          android:background="#0000"
          android:onClick="onClick"
          android:scaleType="fitXY"
          android:src="@drawable/scout" />


      <SeekBar
          android:id="@+id/seekSnipers"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
          android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
          android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
          android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control" />

    <com.google.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" >
            </com.google.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

It's pretty much same for other layouts as well, except for different resources and ID's.
Ad code is same in every layout.

Comment: Please share the xml layout of the activity that fails to load.

Comment: It's not 1 layout/activity that fails to load, basically all activities can crash/fails to load. It goes like this:Menu>activity1>menu>Activity2>Menu>Activity3>Menu: And any next layout/activity that I open will crash

Comment: This error says that there are one or more error(s) in your XML layout, post your xml code if you want some help ;)

Comment: I added XML layout above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

YOu can release resources by using the following code. This should be called in onDestroy() of u=your activity.

```
private void unbindDrawables(View view) {
    if (view.getBackground() != null) {
        view.getBackground().setCallback(null);
    }
    if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++) {
            unbindDrawables(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i));
        }
        ((ViewGroup) view).removeAllViews();
        view.setBackgroundResource(0);
    }
}
```

More over to destroy activity you should call **finish()** after calling next activity.

Comment: but if i have static view then??

Comment: @DigveshPatel Why to use static views?They are bound to leak memory.See this post :- http://blog.vogella.com/2013/03/12/android-why-not-to-use-static-for-view-fields-in-your-activity-or-fragments-by-lars-vogel/

Comment: but if want to update my textview text from diffrent diffrent helper class and that text is common in all activity then??

Comment: you can use static string that is initialized in main activity and use that to update the textview.

Answer (score 0):

You should use OnStop() callback to release the resources that causing the memory leak. You should also use onStop() to perform relatively CPU-intensive shutdown operations.